# Google Drive API v3 Permissions sendNotificationEmail: False -Not Working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am utilizing the Permissions endpoint call of the Google Drive API v3 to assign reader and writer status to a folder within app scripts for a shared google drive. The main goal is to not send the notification email when the permission is shared with a user. I have included the parameter 'sendNotificationEmail: false' in the body of the request however the email is still being sent notifying the user. The code snippet that I am using is below. Am I including the 'sendNotificationEmail' parameter in the wrong part of the request?

```html
if (currTabName == "Testing" && curRange.getColumn() == 2){
   for (var i = row; i < (row+rows); i++) {
     var Email = currSS.getRange(i,2,1,1).getValue();
     try{
      var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FileID/permissions';
      var data = {
        'role': 'writer',
        'type': 'user',
        'sendNotificationEmail': false,
        'emailAddress': Email,
        'supportsAllDrives': true,
      }
      var options = {
        'method'     : 'POST',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'headers'    : { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'yourAccessToken' },
        'payload'    : JSON.stringify(data) // Convert JavaScript object to JSON string
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      Logger.log(response);
     }
     catch(err) {
       Logger.log(err.message);
```

Comment: I can't find that url endpoint

Comment: Here is the reference doc for the url - https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create.

Comment: So this `folderthatstatusisgrantedfor` is not a folder but a fileId

Comment: `folderthatstatusisgrantedfor` could have been `<redacted>` or something similar for a clearer understanding

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have changed the name to FileID to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the method of Permissions: create of Drive API, `sendNotificationEmail` and `supportsAllDrives` are required to be included in the query parameter. I think that this is the reason for your issue. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/folderthatstatusisgrantedfor/permissions';
var data = {
  'role': 'writer',
  'type': 'user',
  'sendNotificationEmail': false,
  'emailAddress': Email,
  'supportsAllDrives': true,
}
var options = {
  'method'     : 'POST',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'headers'    : { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'yourAccessToken' },
  'payload'    : JSON.stringify(data) // Convert JavaScript object to JSON string
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

#### To:

```
var folderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID.

var url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${folderId}/permissions`;
url += "?sendNotificationEmail=false&supportsAllDrives=true";
var data = {
  'role': 'writer',
  'type': 'user',
  'emailAddress': Email,
}
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'headers': { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + 'yourAccessToken' },
  'payload': JSON.stringify(data)
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)

Comment: This worked. Do you know why adding it to the URL worked when passing it in the body didn't? I'm trying to determine how I can think about this for when I have similar issue in the future?

Comment: @SommNinja Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question of `This worked. Do you know why adding it to the URL worked when passing it in the body didn't?`. I think that because `role`, `type`, `emailAddress` are required to be included in the request body, while `sendNotificationEmail` and `supportsAllDrives` are required to be included in the query parametar.

Comment: I have accepted the answer. Thanks for the follow up

Comment: @SommNinja Thank you for your response.